# Add SSL on top of existing TCP connection

Tags: encryption, tls, tcp

This may sound as basic question for some but I have never done such thing.

Imagine I basically have simple TCP client implemented on C# (e.g. TCPClient class) and simple TCP server implemented using C++ (e.g. using sockets). This connection works well.

Now I want to add SSL on top of this connection. Do I have to implement this in code too? Can't I use some standard tools? Like maybe how web sites are using it?

Can't I do it without writing code?

Both client and server use Windows.

Basically I want my above mentioned TCP connection and read/writes to go through some secure tunnel such as SSL. Or maybe even VPN?

Answer (score 2):

> Can't I do it without writing code?
>
> Basically I want my above mentioned TCP connection and read/writes to go through some secure tunnel such as SSL. Or maybe even VPN?

You can use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html), use a VPN, use a tunnel done with SSH etc. Details depend on your infrastructure, that is which software you can install, which is already available etc. Since you want to have end-to-end encryption you need the necessary software on both sides of the connection.

Comment: Thanks can that software you linked work autonomously? E.g. if my client restarts

Comment: @user200312: It is probably possible to start the tunnel software together with your client but details depend on your actual environment.

Comment: you mean the stunnel soft? or other like SSH? Yep if computer reboots I need them to start manually... and this way I don't have to change code right?

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing with the client.  If you're connecting to a static host all the time, it's really trivial to setup some simple scripts to make this all automatic.  If you're connecting to a variety of hosts dynamically, it'll be a bit trickier since you'll have to co-ordinate the two pieces of software.

Comment: @SteveSether: server is one. But do you think it is possible to write software which will automatically download say VPN or some similar software and install on target machines and configure also that on restart they start automatically? also specify other configurations

Comment: @user200312 Sure.  Why not?

Comment: @user200312: but the more effort you need to install and configure some external software the more you should think about implementing TLS instead inside your application. There is a reason servers and clients usually have TLS inside instead of requiring outside solutions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich:Yeah one part of server is on C++ and first I am reluctant to add new code to it. If it were C# it is easier. Btw. any links how the some software would install/configure say VPN (or other similar software) so that it starts automatically and specified destination host parameters etc.?

Comment: @user200312: I think you have to first decide on a possible solution and then you can look how to configure it. I have no experience with any of these done automatic, because I usually do the SSL part inside the application. And there are various links to using C++ with SSL, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236526/looking-for-a-high-level-c-ssl-library).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich:Ok, one more question. Is this approach say with stunnel secure? I mean can't the attack intercept data from when my software sends it and before it reaches stunnel (on client machine)? Also can stunnel accept many connections from different clients?

Comment: @user200312: Of course the data are only protected while inside the tunnel and software on the local machine might sniff it (maybe root permissions needed). And yes, stunnel can accept multiple connections at the same time.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: That's a weakness right? I am referring only within single machine when data is sent like this: MySoft-->Stunnel. In between MySoft and Stunnel. If SLL is implemented inside my project, this is not a threat?

Comment: @user200312: yes, if SSL is implemented inside the application itself then the plain data cannot be sniffed outside the application. You would need to inject some code into the application itself to get to the plain data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich:Do you think fact that data can be sniffed form application till it reaches stunnel is big threat? assuming someone can compromise PC? I find stunnel approach convenient because you don't have to modify code

Comment: @user200312: this fully depends on the security of your system. If it is impossible for an attacker to get the necessary permissions on the machine then you are secure.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich:But those permissions get activated depending on what password user enters when logging in? Or I can create some ONLY one defaut account - without password even, but limited permissions?

Comment: @user200312: your questions move into the directions of setting up specific tools or how to do it in your application etc. I think stackoverflow.com and superuser.com are better for this kind of questions and for any general questions regarding system security I would suggest to ask a new question instead of handling everything inside this question.

Answer (score 1):

If your want to make your connection secure, you have 2 options:

- Configure IPSec policy. With IPSec, two *machines* create secure tunnel between them and route your traffic with this channel. It is absolutelly transparent for client and server applications.
- You may create VPN connection (OpenSSL, IPSec/L2TP etc) it is transparent for your client too.

You also may change your code to use `SslStream` class. No need to implement TLS by hand, but your code still need to be changed

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming in golang there is [tls package](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/) that implements tls client and server. You could use those to wrap your connection into TLS.

.NET Framework and .NET Core have [SslStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netcore-2.2) that is accessible from C#.

Answer (score 0):

In general when you want to secure a service or you want to access to a service that is not secure my recommendation is start by making a **ssh tunnel**, is easy and in general you have ssh everywhere.